# Regex to capture '/etc/services'

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture some info from the `\etc\services` file on my UNIX machine,
But I capture the wrong value, while also overcomplicating it I think.

**What I have now**

```
with open('/etc/services') as ports_file:
    lines = ports_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print re.findall('((\w*\-*\w+)+\W+(\d+)\/(tcp|udp))', line)
```

But it is yielding incorrect values like this:

```
[('dircproxy\t57000/tcp', 'dircproxy', '57000', 'tcp')]
[('tfido\t\t60177/tcp', 'tfido', '60177', 'tcp')]
[('fido\t\t60179/tcp', 'fido', '60179', 'tcp')]
```

I would want it like this:

```
[('dircproxy', '57000', 'tcp')]
[('tfido', '60177', 'tcp')]
[('fido', '60179', 'tcp')]
```

I think this `(\w*\-*\w+)+` is needed in my regex because some are defined like this `this-should-capture`

Comment: Remove the outer parentheses.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I suck at regex. Thanks alot

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use a regex here at all? Seems more like a job for `split()`.

Comment: It is because I want to capture port_number and port_type at once, *correct me if i'm wrong*

Comment: `re.split('[\s/]+', line.split('#', 1)[0])` will do that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Indeed it does `re.split('[\s/]+', line.split('#', 1)[0])[:3]` to capture what I want

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And alot faster too!

Comment: It is faster because your regex is really bad at the very start. `(\w*\-*\w+)+` is a classical example of a `(\w+)+` that leads to catastrophical backtracking when there are more and more subpatterns after this one. It must be re-written as `\w+(?:-\w+)*`. The whole pattern would look like [`r'(\w+(?:-\w+)*)\W+(\d+)/(tcp|udp)'`](https://regex101.com/r/16s8ND/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest coming at this from a different perspective: Instead of matching the field values, match the separators between them.

```
print re.split(r'[\s/]+', line.split('#', 1)[0])[:3]
```

The first `line.split('#', 1)[0]` removes comments (anything after the first `#` in the file).

Answer (score 0):

It personally wouldn't use regex here. Look at the solution below and try to see if it fits your needs (also note that you can iterate over the file object directly):

```
services = []
with open('/etc/services') as serv:
    for line in serv:
        l = line.split()
        if len(l) < 2:
            continue
        if '/tcp' in l[1] or '/udp' in l[1]:
            port, protocol = l[1].split('/')
            services.append((l[0], port, protocol))
```